# How to set attributes in backbone models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to implement my app using backbone but I might have got something misunderstood.

I want to specify certain attributes(title etc.) while using certain default values. But the custom attributes are not set, why?

```
        var DataMapper = {
            Models: {},
            Collections: {},
            Views: {},
            Templates: {}
        };


        DataMapper.Views.OperatorView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: "#op-panel",
            operators: [],
            events: {
                "click #concat-op-btn": "addConcatOp"
            },
            addConcatOp: function () {
                var concatOperator = new DataMapper.Models.OpContainerBox({title: "Concat", inputCount: 2, outputCount: 1});
                this.operators.push(concatOperator);
                concatOperator.drawContainer();
            }
        });


        DataMapper.Models.OpContainerBox = Backbone.Model.extend({
            title: "Operator",
            inputCount: 0,
            outputCount: 0,
            defaults: {
                x: 400,
                y: 40,
                leaves: [],
                height: 20,
                width: 120
            },
            drawContainer: function () {
                console.log(this.title); //outputs "Operator" not "Concat"
            }
        });
        new DataMapper.Views.OperatorView();
```

Comment: The `console.log(this.title);` in your `drawContainer` behaves the way it expected to be, (i.e it will output the default value which you set in your `OpContainerBox` model. The `concat` will get outputed when you console.log our `concatOperator` variable because there is where you create an instance for your model.

Answer (score 5):

Backbone model *attributes* are not the same as JavaScript object *properties*. Attributes are stored in the [`attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) property and you use [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) and [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) to work with them; properties are attached to `this` and directly accessed via `this.property_name`.

When you say this:

```
DataMapper.Models.OpContainerBox = Backbone.Model.extend({
    title: "Operator"
});
```

`title` will be a property, not an attribute. When you say this:

```
DataMapper.Models.OpContainerBox.new({
    title: 'Concat'
});
```

Backbone will set the `title` attribute to `'Concat'`.

If you change your `console.log` call to:

```
console.log(this.title, this.get('title'));
```

you should see both `'Operator'` and `'Concat'` in the console.

All the defaults should go in the [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) property and if any of the defaults are mutable, then you should use a function for `defaults` to prevent accidental reference sharing:

```
DataMapper.Models.OpContainerBox = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            title: "Operator",
            inputCount: 0,
            outputCount: 0,
            x: 400,
            y: 40,
            leaves: [],
            height: 20,
            width: 120
        };
    },
    drawContainer: function () {
        console.log(this.get('title'));
    }
});
```

If you don't use a function for `defaults` then all `OpContainerBox` instances will share exactly the same `defaults.leaves` array through their prototype.

You'll also want to be sure to use `get` to access the attributes: `this.get('title')` not `this.title`.

This "reference sharing through the prototype" problem can also cause you problems with the `operators` array in your `OperatorView` so you might want to say this instead:

```
DataMapper.Views.OperatorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#op-panel",
    events: {
        "click #concat-op-btn": "addConcatOp"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.operators = [ ]; // <---- One distinct array per instance.
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: So to get my target values, I should always use `this.get('title')` ?

Comment: Yes, use `this.get('title')` to get the `'title'` attribute from `this`, or more generally, `model.get('title')` where `model` is the model instance.