# Backbone fetch - "url" property or function must be specified error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Pretty new to Backbone, so please mind my ignorance...

I have a simple GallereyModel:

```
var GalleryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        id: "",
        width: ""
    },
    url : ""
});
```

When the model is updated, the function `galleryModelUpdate` is called

```
var GalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.galleryModelUpdate);
},
galleryModelUpdate: function(){
    console.log("updated gallery model"+this.model.get("id");
    if (this.model.get("url")){  
        console.log("fetching " + this.model.get("url")); // this line prints with the correct url
        this.model.fetch({ // this line gives error
            success: function(){
                console.log("fetched succesfully!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

});

I am printing the value of url on the model before fetch is called, so not sure why is it throwing the "url" undefined error?

Many thanks for your help in advance

Comment: but you're not setting `url` in the fetch - `this.model.fetch({
    url: this.model.get("url"),
    success: function(){
        console.log("fetched succesfully!");
    }
});`

Comment: Oh I see. I was under the impression the `fetch` call would look for the `url` in the model automatically. Thank you, that resolved the problem

Comment: Backbone will look at the `url` *property* but not the *attribute*.  Your `url: ""` is a property, `this.model.get('url')` is the attribute but they're not related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39820057/479863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the [`url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) or the [`urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) model properties needs to be defined in order for the model to fetch.
You can set your model url to point to the url data attribute:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function () {
    return this.get('url');
  }
});
```